# Visual / artistic representations of code

Tags: diagram, abstract, representation

I don't know if there is a name for this.  What I am interested in is what sort of graphical programs there are for representing code or code development in a high level, abstract and beautiful way.

The only example I know of something like this is a video I saw a while ago which used glowing orbs moving around a repository to show user code activity around a large open source project- although I can't find it again.

I'm sorry if this question is too vague.  I was just thinking last night about how you could show a project skeleton to somebody as a picture and whether you could do it in such a way that they could identify the general shape and/or tidyness of the codebase at a glance.  If you could watch a project grow, what would it look like?  What are the problems, if any, with writing a parser to accomplish this?

I'm looking for something more abstract than UML diagrams!

Comment: "It's a UNIX system! I know this!"

Comment: YOu might like this: http://sq.ro/malwarez.php

Comment: I had a couple ideas until you added the requirement of beautiful... :)

Comment: @KB22: cool link. You should make it a real answer.

Comment: @BBlake: beauty is in the eye of the coder.

Comment: Oh, I found the repository visualisation tool I mentioned. It is called code_swarm and is Open Source, very cool program too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [visual complexity.](http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/)

Comment: Wow, that's just the sort of thing I was looking for. Great link

Comment: @Sam, I had found a site (project) to generate such images but I forgot to bookmark it :-/